# Run android on windows 7

Tags: windows

All I want to do running Android on Windows 7 is using whatsapp for certain group discussion.

I tried BlueStacks, but it causing keyboard issue, at many times, certain key act like got stuck, keep repeating, and when this happen, I have to restart my windows.
quit the bluestack won't help.

now I want to try other (free) option, any recommendation?
youwave is not free.
I come across this androvm, but the file type is ova , no idea how to run it at present.

just to re-clarify:

I already running WhatsApp over BlueStack on my Windows 7 64 bits.

But it comes with a side effect, very bad. At time, my keyboard seems like got 1 key stuck, and keep repeatively pressing it unstopped.

the keyboard is absolute fine. I kill/quit BlueStack if I don't plan to use the WhatsApp, which is auto-start whenever i login.

when the funny keyboard issue happened, the only way to resolve it is reboot, quit the BlueStack won't help at all.

Comment: android-x86 perhaps?

Comment: You're probably wasting time if you're doing this just for WhatsApp. WhatsApp won't let you run it on anything without an active phone connection. Try taking the SIM card out of your phone and rebooting it and WhatsApp will complain and fail to work even if you have a wifi connection. They do all of their authentication based on your phone connection details.

Comment: Why not try [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com)?

Comment: I already runnning WhatsApp over BlueStack. It's working. The problem is with the buggy keyboard behavior.

Comment: what's the downvote about?

Comment: I re-upvoted. You really could have worked harder on the grammar and capitalization though. I also added an answer. Please try Andy emulator. Excellent software and super easy to install

Answer (score 1):

You could simply unplug the keyboard and plug it back in. Works for me every time.

Comment: How do you unplug a software keyboard? His keyboard problem is in software

Answer (score 0):

You could install the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and run an instance of Android through the emulator. Probably not the simplest solution but the emulator usually runs pretty well for developers.

Comment: While this will let you install APK's, it still won't work with WhatsApp, which requires a cellular connection and a phone number.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I was not aware of that because I don't use this app.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can use **Andy** for Windows. It's heavy software but extremely powerful for testing or just having fun!

Andy is definitely the simplest option.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/); works as emulator.

Comment: You did see that the Asker has already said he tried Bluestacks and that it didn't work out?

Comment: actually, it worked. but it has a side effect, funny keyboard issue.